# Difference between qiskit SPSA optimize and minimize in runtime program

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience, pennylane, qiskit-runtime

I use [this](https://docs.pennylane.ai/projects/qiskit/en/latest/devices/runtime.html) tutorial with pennylane-qiskit.vqe_runtime_runner to familiarize myself with qiskit runtime using pennylane. Thereby, I wonder:

What is the difference between [qiskit.algorithms.optimizers.SPSA](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.algorithms.optimizers.SPSA.html#qiskit.algorithms.optimizers.SPSA) optimize and minimize? More precise, what is the difference between

```
    spsa = SPSA(**optimizer_config, callback=callback)
    res=spsa.minimize(vqe_func,x0)
```

and

```
    spsa = SPSA(**optimizer_config, callback=callback)
    x, loss, nfev = spsa.optimize(num_params, vqe_func, initial_point=x0)
    res = OptimizeResult(
                 fun=loss,
                 x=x,
                 nit=optimizer_config["maxiter"],
                 nfev=nfev,
                 message="Optimization terminated successfully.",
                 success=True,
             )
```

?

Both return a SciPy OptimizerResult object, but one works in the tutorial (optimize) and the other (minimize) gives an error message stating `Òbject of type Optimizer Result is not serializable`.

**Edit**: Update on workaround to make minimize work:

Gives mentioned error message: (using minimize)

```
    spsa = SPSA(**optimizer_config, callback=callback)
    res=spsa.minimize(vqe_func,x0)
```

Works: (using optimize)

```
    spsa = SPSA(**optimizer_config, callback=callback)
    x, loss, nfev = spsa.optimize(num_params, vqe_func, initial_point=x0)
    res = OptimizeResult(
                 fun=loss,
                 x=x,
                 nit=optimizer_config["maxiter"],
                 nfev=nfev,
                 message="Optimization terminated successfully.",
                 success=True,
             )
```

Works: (using minimize, converting to its values and back to a OptimizerResults object)

```
    spsa = SPSA(**optimizer_config, callback=callback)
    result_obj=spsa.minimize(vqe_func,x0)
    loss=result_obj.fun
    x= result_obj.x
    nfev=result_obj.nfev
    res = OptimizeResult(
                 fun=loss,
                 x=x,
                 nit=optimizer_config["maxiter"],
                 nfev=nfev,
                 message="Optimization terminated successfully.",
                 success=True,
             )
```

**Edit:** The answer supplementary to .. on why the second example using minimize is needed is because the pennylane runtime code assumes the output of the optimizer to be a *SciPy* `OptimizerResult`object which differs from the Qiskit `OptimizerResult`object (output of the `minimize` method) (thanks to rmoyard on Github).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`SPSA.optimize()`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.algorithms.optimizers.SPSA.optimize.html) method is deprecated since Qiskit 0.37 (Terra 0.21). You should always use [`SPSA.minimize()`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.algorithms.optimizers.SPSA.minimize.html).

Both methods support the same arguments but `minimize()` follows the interface of `scipy.optimize` and returns `OptimizerResult` object where `optimize()` returns
`point, value, nfev`

where,

- `point`: is a one-dimensional `numpy.ndarray[float]` containing the solution,
- `value`: is a float with the objective function value, and
- `nfev`: number of objective function calls made if available or None.

The current implementation of `optimize()` method just calls `minimize()` and extract these values from its result (see [here](https://qiskit.org/documentation/_modules/qiskit/algorithms/optimizers/spsa.html#SPSA.optimize))

Comment: Thank you for this clear explanation. How can it then be that one works fine while the other gives an error message that it is not json serializable?